# Bootstrap Modal working in Xamp server and not working properly in Remote server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a code using twitter Bootstrap, It's working well in local server(Xamp) but when I transfer the same file to remote server the twitter bootstrap modal does not work properly. Anyone who knows what is wrong, or are there any thing that I should install in my server? I am using Linux server Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you in advance

```js
 <script>
 


$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.loaded', function (e) {

    // get a data attribute value from the clicked element
    var merchantName = $(e.relatedTarget).data('merchant-name');

    // and set the content of the shown remote modal
    $('#myModalLabel').text("shown.bs.loaded event triggered");

});

// cleanup the content of the hidden remote modal because it is cached
$('#reservationModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {

    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');

});
 
 </script>
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Content Has not loaded Successfully</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="te">If You see</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
    </div>


<a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo base_url('admin/dashboard/book_thisroute/'.$dashboard_upcoming->tour_id); ?>" data-target="#myModal" data-merchant-name="Bob's House of Pancakes" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><?php echo lang('Book ticket'); ?></a>
```

Comment: How could we possibly tell without seeing your code or server? Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Its very hard to imagine like that. 
you will have to elaborate, or provide screenshots, or errors or code.

Comment: I have provided the code

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser console?

Comment: the modal will open in a whole page, no errors

Comment: And when you say "it does not work properly", what does that mean? We are not psychic.